# Angular 8 - Lazy loading yourself - AoT "No NgModule metada"

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm working on a Angular project which can load in widgets lazily, as well as loading them in from a UMD bundle.

I am currently facing some issues when building my current project for production with AoT enabled.

## The problem

The AoT build does not provide a compiler. Therefore I am providing the `JITCompiler` to the application.

When compiling a module using the `import(path/to/module)` in production mode with the `JITCompiler`, I receive

```
main.e522a776bacf42032766.js:1 ERROR Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'function(){}'.
    at e.resolve (main.e522a776bacf42032766.js:1)
    at e.getNgModuleMetadata (main.e522a776bacf42032766.js:1)
    at e._loadModules (main.e522a776bacf42032766.js:1)
    at e._compileModuleAndComponents (main.e522a776bacf42032766.js:1)
    at e.compileModuleAsync (main.e522a776bacf42032766.js:1)
    at e.compileModuleAsync (main.e522a776bacf42032766.js:1)
    at t.project (main.e522a776bacf42032766.js:1)
    at t._tryNext (main.e522a776bacf42032766.js:1)
    at t._next (main.e522a776bacf42032766.js:1)
    at t.next (main.e522a776bacf42032766.js:1)
```

### What changed

Listing the properties of the module, there is a difference between `ng serve` and `ng serve --prod`: `[ngInjectorDef]` in development serve as opposed to `[]` in production.

I was wondering if anyone else faced the issue?

## Reproduction/testing yourself

There is a working stackblitz of the minimalistic project here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpzmle

To serve to production as a production server, you'll have to:

- Download the zip
- Extract the zip
- Run `npm install` in the extract directory
- Adjust tsconfig.json (I cannot adjust it in stackblitz?)

  - Change module: es2015 to esnext
- run `ng serve --prod` and serve to `localhost:4200`

An alternative to this manual labour is following the steps on https://github.com/juristr/manually-lazy-load-ngmodule/issues/1.
It's a project implementing a similar concept, plagued by the same problem.

Comment: Looking further into the issue, I have found these sources:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20875, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9306#issuecomment-378304155.
The issue is that the decorators get discarded on the module I wish to dynamically load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special thanks to Antur84 on Github for his reply [here](https://github.com/juristr/manually-lazy-load-ngmodule/issues/1#issuecomment-539161888)

The compiler looks for objects with 'loadChildren' properties. If the property is of the syntax `import(...).then(m => m.SOME_EXPORT)`, the url is traced and compiled into the appropriate factories.

So I had to refactor my callback key and the return type of the passed function.